# SmsManager, send attachment in sms

Tags: android, file, attachment, mms, smsmanager

How do I add an "attachment" into my SmsManager object when I'm trying tro send an sms?

My current function for sending a normal sms is:

```
public void send() {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(this.number, null, this.message, null, null);
}
```

I have looked a little bit at the sendDataMessage() but don't really understand it.. any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

## EDIT

I don't want to use Intent for this. I have a List with Bitmap images that I want to send via an SMS/MMS. So I don't want to invoke the SMS app in my application. I want to send attachments "dynamically" depending on what's in my List.

## SOLUTION

A friend of mine just posted me this link to a library: https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms

```
Message mMessage = new Message(textToSend, addressToSendTo);
mMessage.setImage(mBitmap);   // not necessary for voice or sms messages
mMessage.setType(Message.TYPE_SMSMMS);  // could also be Message.TYPE_VOICE
```

Haven't tried it yet, but it seems to be the real deal. Hope it's for good use for someone else too.

Comment: start to explore here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/telephony/

Comment: you don't want to send an SMS, that would be an MMS. which is significantly more complex.

Comment: Yea, I understand that. My statement will be: "No attachment = SMS" or "Attachment = MMS". But the problem is that I haven't found anything usefull yet.. everyone suggest me to use Invent and that won't help me in this case.

Comment: @Snuffish So, did the "solution" work?

Answer (score -1):

follow the code

```
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content");
     sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
     startActivity(sendIntent);
```

and add permission

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I actually don't want to use Intent for this.

I have a List with Bitmap images that I want to send via an SMS/MMS. So I don't want to invoke the SMS app in my application. I want to send attachments "dynamically" depending on what's in my List.